# $f_n(x) = [x_n+g(x)]^2$ won't converge uniformly when $x_n\to 0$ and $g$ is unbounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of reals such that $x_n\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$. Show that if $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded, then:

$$f_n(x) = [x_n+g(x)]^2$$

won't converge uniformly

I tried to expand in

$$f_n(x) = x_n^2+2x_ng(x)+g^2(x)$$

I think $x_n^2$ will go to $0$ also, but I don't know anything about the rest. Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: The domain of $g$ is $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow (g(x))^{2}$ pointwise. Assuming that it is uniformly convergent, then choosing some $N$ such that $|(x_{n}+g(x))^{2}-(g(x))^{2}|<1$ for all such $x$ and $n\geq N$. Letting $n=N$ be fixed, then $|x_{N}^{2}+2x_{N}g(x)|<1$ for all such $x$. Simply varying $x$ such that $g(x)$ becomes as large (plus or minus) as possible, it will violate the inequality.

Comment: In fact, your question might have some little flaw, if $x_{n}=0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then it will become uniformly. If $x_{n}$'s are infinitely many $0$ but not eventually $0$, remember to pick one large $N$ such that $x_{N}$ is nonzero